# Indexed DB - compound index query where one or the other matches

Tags: indexeddb

Apologies if my terminology is incorrect or this isn't well explained. I created something a while back with a websql database and would like to try changing it to an indexed DB.

I've created this index which allows me to find the objects where the hometeam is a certain value and the away team is a certain value:

```
objectStore.createIndex("homeAway", ["hometeam", "awayteam"], {unique: false});
```

So if I'm looking for a match between USA (hometeam) and Russia (awayteam) I'd get what I'm after:

```
var range = IDBKeyRange.only([hometeam, awayteam]);
var index = objectStore.index("homeAway");
```

But what if I wanted to use this .only method to find a match where a certain team is playing home OR away. Something like this:

```
var range = IDBKeyRange.only([hometeam || awayteam]);
```

Where if I entered Russia as both home and away it would find where they were either home or away. Is this possible?

Comment: In theory, and I think this is a bad suggestion so I'm not posting it as an answer, you could just do 2 searches and make use of promises to know when both are done so you can combine the results. Or heck, since it is only two, just do one after the other and suffer a bit of callback hell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening and index on two fields at once it's not possible however there is a indexed solution for your case.

You need to create a new index for an array field which will contain both teams with `multiEntry` property set to `true`.

```
objectStore.createIndex("teams", ["teams"], {unique: false, multiEntry: true});
```

And then store both teams as array of strings into that field

```
var obj = {
    hometeam: "Russia",
    awayteam: "Usa",
    teams: ["Russia", "Usa"]
}
```

Now when you query the database on that field you should get all games in which `Russia` is playing:

```
var index = objectStore.index("teams");
var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only("Russia");
var cursorRequest = index.openCursor(keyRange);
```

Comment: Duh. Of course, this is just like adding "tagging" to content and searching for the tag. I've actually done this before and it didn't even occur to me. :)

Comment: Opening an index on two fields at once is possible. Otherwise this is a good answer.

Comment: Yeah you can create compound index, but for this scenario that index won't be useful.